# Latex leaves indentation in references (\bibliography)

Tags: spacing, bibliographies

I have the same problem as in [Latex leaves blank space in references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96923/latex-leaves-blank-space-in-references), but I am using the `\bibliography{}` command.

Is there any way to remove the indentation?

[image]

```
\documentclass[urlsf]{usmthesis}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

\begin{singlespace}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{singlespace}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setlength{\protect\cftbeforechapskip}{1pc}}
\end{document}
```

Inside the `usmthesis.cls`,

```
\RequirePackage[numbers]{natbib}
%\RequirePackage{apacite}
%\RequirePackage{natbib}
\addto\captionsenglish{%
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
}
\setlength\bibsep{1em}
\setlength\bibhang{1.5em}
\renewcommand\bibfont{\singlespace}
```

The indentation that I meant was, from my latex:

[image]

In my `usmthesis.bbl` file, I have set

```
begin{thebibliography}{100}
```

but to no avail.

Comment: What space are you hoping to get rid of from that image? It would also be helpful for you to read about what a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) is, and then to provide one for this (and future) questions.

Comment: I don't think this is [tag:indentation] as much as it is [tag:spacing]. I've retagged.

Comment: Where can we find `usmthesis.cls`?

Comment: Strange how [this version of `usmthesis.cls`](http://liantze.penguinattack.org/files/usmthesis/usmthesis-1.6.1.zip) has a different layout than you present (original [source](http://liantze.penguinattack.org/latextypesetting.html#usmthesis)).

Comment: oh the original source did not came from usmthesis.cls. I will post up the reference created by usmthesis.cls

Comment: (not tried.)  the setting of the indentation is probably overridden by `\bibhang`, which is not large enough to accommodate an extra digit.  since digits in computer modern have width `.5em`, increasing that to `\bibhang{2em}` should result in a uniform indentation.

Comment: @Barbara, I tried changing bibhang parameters as well as comment out the line as well but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original author of `usmthesis.cls` was kind enough to reply my e-mail and offer me a solution.

Adding

```
\renewcommand{\bibnumfmt}[1]{\makebox[1.75em][l]{[#1]}}
```

at the preamble will force the bib number label to take up exactly `1.75em` width, regardless of what the number is. If there is more than 100 references, that length value can be increased.

Comment: If this has solved your problem, don't forget to accept your answer as the best answer.